# Unable to use FeatureColumn with category column in Keras Functional API

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.x

I am using Keras Functional API from Tensorflow 2.2 to build a model that uses features columns. I followed the guide [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-build-a-wide-and-deep-model-using-keras-in-tensorflow-2-0-2f7a236b5a4b) and tutorial [Classify structured data](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/feature_columns) to make the code snippet:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import feature_column
from tensorflow.keras import layers

def df_to_dataset(dataframe, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
    dataframe = dataframe.copy()
    labels = dataframe.pop('target')
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(dataframe), labels))
    if shuffle:
        ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(dataframe))
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
    return ds

if __name__ == '__main__':
    URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/applied-dl/heart.csv'
    dataframe = pd.read_csv(URL)
    batch_size = 5  # A small batch sized is used for demonstration purposes
    train_ds = df_to_dataset(dataframe, batch_size=batch_size)
    example_batch = next(iter(train_ds))
    feature_columns = []
    inputs = {'age': tf.keras.layers.Input(name='age', shape=(), dtype='float32'),
              'thal': tf.keras.layers.Input(name='thal', shape=(), dtype='string')}
    feature_columns.append(feature_column.numeric_column('age'))
    thal = feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
        'thal', ['fixed', 'normal', 'reversible'])
    thal_one_hot = feature_column.indicator_column(thal)
    feature_columns.append(thal_one_hot)
    x = layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns)(inputs)
    preds = layers.Dense(1)(x)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=preds)
    print(model(example_batch))
```

Unfortunately this code fails with an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 42, in <module>
    print(model(example_batch))
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 968, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 717, in call
    return self._run_internal_graph(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 837, in _run_internal_graph
    y = self._conform_to_reference_input(y, ref_input=x)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 961, in _conform_to_reference_input
    tensor = math_ops.cast(tensor, dtype=ref_input.dtype)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py", line 180, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py", line 789, in cast
    x = gen_math_ops.cast(x, base_type, name=name)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py", line 1971, in cast
    _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 6653, in raise_from_not_ok_status
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnimplementedError: Cast int64 to string is not supported [Op:Cast]
```

When i drop category column 'thal' from feature_columns, it works without error. Unfortunately, i need to pass category column into my model. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Is your goal to Train the Model? Can you please explain what exactly you want to achieve with `print(model(example_batch))`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to pass `Inputs` in the code, x = `layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns)` because `feature_columns` already comprises the `Feature Columns` corresponding to all the `Features`.

Complete working code for Training the Model with `heart.csv` data is shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import feature_column
from tensorflow.keras import layers

def df_to_dataset(dataframe, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
    dataframe = dataframe.copy()
    labels = dataframe.pop('target')
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(dataframe), labels))
    if shuffle:
        ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(dataframe))
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
    return ds

URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/applied-dl/heart.csv'
dataframe = pd.read_csv(URL)

print(dataframe.head())

batch_size = 5  # A small batch sized is used for demonstration purposes
train_ds = df_to_dataset(dataframe, batch_size=batch_size)

example_batch = next(iter(train_ds))

feature_columns = []

age = feature_column.numeric_column('age')

feature_columns.append(age)


thal = feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
    'thal', ['fixed', 'normal', 'reversible'])

thal_one_hot = feature_column.indicator_column(thal)

feature_columns.append(thal_one_hot)



print(feature_columns)

x = layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  x,
  layers.Dense(1)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_ds,
          epochs=5)

#print(model(example_batch))
```

Please let me know if you need any other information or if you face any other error, and I will be Happy to help you.

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!

Answer (score 0):

example_batch contains both feature batch and label batch, and model expects only features as inputs.

Following code should work:

```
feature_batch, label_batch = next(iter(train_ds))
model(feature_batch)
```

or:

```
example_batch = next(iter(train_ds))[0]
model(example_batch)
```